# Can anyone identify this font?

Tags: font-identification

This font can be seen in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Art Nouveau style font [Boffo](https://www.wfonts.com/font/boffo-ssi) via wfonts.com

[image: boffo font]

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg Thank by accepting the answer - only one click and someone else also has a possiblity to notice that here's the right answer.